# How can I switch tab bar tabs using left and right swipe gestures?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar, gesture

I have a `UITabBarController` with two tabs connected to it. How can I use left and right swipe gestures in the two views to switch tabs left and right?

I've seen other questions similar to this but all of them use Objective-C. Also, if this can be all done in the storyboard, I'd prefer that over having to use Swift code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following swipe gestures to your viewcontroller view

```
 let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(swiped))
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped))
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
// below code create swipe gestures function
// MARK: - swiped
@objc  func swiped(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
if gesture.direction == .left {
    if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! < 2
    { // set here  your total tabs
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex += 1
    }
} else if gesture.direction == .right {
    if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! > 0 {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex -= 1
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @TheLukeGuy The swiped function (lines 25-45 in your screenshot) do not go inside viewDidLoad, put that outside as its own function.

Comment: @skladek Now it's not doing anything when I swipe, here's the code: http://prntscr.com/k4tajg

Comment: All of that should be on the UIViewControllers that your tab bar controller is displaying, not on the tab bar controller itself.